# Learning C++ in Data Structures.

Tags: c++, structure

This is so simple but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code: Main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "throttle.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    throttle example;
    example.shut_off();
    int in = 2;
    example.shift(4);
    cout << "At position 2, the flow is " << example.flow() << endl;

}
```

throttle.h

```
#ifndef THROTTLE_H
#define THROTTLE_H

class throttle {
public:
    //throttle();
    //throttle(const throttle& orig);
    //virtual ~throttle();

    void shift(int amount);
    bool is_on();
    double flow() const;
    void shut_off(); 

private:
    int position;

};

#endif
```

And throttle.cpp

```
#include "throttle.h"
/*
throttle::throttle() {
}

throttle::throttle(const throttle& orig) {
}

throttle::~throttle() {
}
*/
//Pre:
//POST: Returns double position / total positions
double throttle::flow() const {
    return double (position / 6);
}

bool throttle::is_on() {
    return (flow() > 0);
}

void throttle::shift(int amount) {

    position += amount;

    if (amount > 6)
        position = 6;
    else if (amount < 0)
        position = 0;
}

void throttle::shut_off() {
    position = 0;    
}
```

My problem is not knowing C++ obviously, but in my main, why doesn't my shift method work? Function is probably the right word instead of method.

My logic is:

Call shut_off method to set the position to 0.

Call the shift method to set the position to 4. Not returning anything, just setting the position to 4. But it's not doing it.

Any one fluent in C++, can you also point out any other "bad" coding practices as well. (I'm aware I didn't write pre and post conditions in the implementation)

Comment: When you say 'not doing' what does it actually do?

Comment: Sorry should have put the output but the output is:
"At position 2, the flow is 0;

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you say 'not doing' you probably mean your flow is 0? But that is expected, since you are dividing your position by 6, and since position is integers, as well as 6, you end up with integer 0. If you wanto to have double number, you need to convert position to double before division:

```
(double) position / 6
```

Your code, on the other hand, converts result of the division (integer 0) to double 0.